# Open lead in a variant of Spades, where players must play a winner if able (CallBreak)

Tags: variants, spades, trick-taking-games

**CallBreak** is an Indian variant of Spades, The rules differences from normal Spades are:

1. Solo (no partnerships)
2. Possible bids are from 1 to 8  (no Nil bids)
3. **Players must play a stronger card than the current trick winner, if able.**
4. Can lead first trick with a spade (No “spades broken” rule).
5. No bags penalty.
6. Game ends after 5 rounds.

### My question is, what is a strong open lead in CallBreak?

While this question could be seen as opinion based, it is not so since I have access to a simulator of the game which allows me to compare clones of the same AI-agent that differ solely in the open lead, thus finding which open lead is better.

---

It is available to play in many mobile game applications and also at http://callbreak.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made several AI agents that plays CallBreak. My current strongest **rule-based** agent uses the following lead:

1. If starting with 5+ spades, lead them: lead boss, otherwise lead lowest.
2. Lead sidesuit Boss.
3. Lead strongest below the second-Boss from sidesuit with a second boss.
4. Lead low from Short sidesuit.
5. Lead Trash - low from worst suit.

---

Terminology:

- Lead - the first card in the trick.
- Open lead - the lead in the first trick of the round.
- Boss - Strongest card in the suit, based on the cards that were already played. For example, the King is the Boss if the Ace was played.